# Installing the latest version of GHC

Tags: apt, package-management, haskell

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.5 and I have some troubles installing the latest version of GHC (Haskell compiler), which should be 8.0.2.
My `apt-get` installs 7.6.3.

I tried

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

but it did not work. I also tried adding the repository for Haskell manually

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hvr/ghc
sudo apt-get update
```

but it still installs only version 7.6.3.
What could be the issue?

Comment: I guess it's happening because you're running 14.04. I have 17.04 and doing same you did, installed ghc 8.0.2 naturally

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's happening because you have all repositories set to `trusty` in `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. You can change all `trusty` words to `zesty`, `apt update` repositories and install `ghc` again for [8.0.2-1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/ghc). After that return all back to `trusty`. **But it may break dependencies and corrupt your system!** I strongly don't recommend this.

What you can try is download version you want and install it with `dpkg -i <package>.deb`

At the right-top of [this page](https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/ghc) choose version (trusty/xenial/zesty) and at the bottom of the page choose your architecture for download links. I suppose there will also be some problems with dependencies (which you may have to solve), but this isn't so much dangerous as the first solution.